# LaTeX issue on macOS: pdflatex and kpsewhich only work with sudo

Tags: latex, sudo

Hello Stack Exchange community,

I'm currently facing a perplexing issue with my LaTeX setup on macOS, and I'm seeking some guidance to understand and resolve the problem.

*Issue Description*:

When attempting to use pdflatex or kpsewhich without sudo, I encounter errors related to file not found, particularly with the article.cls file. However, these commands behave correctly when preceded by sudo. This issue is affecting my ability to compile LaTeX documents without administrative privileges.

*Details*:

1. **Operating System**: macOS
2. **LaTeX Distribution**: TeX Live installed via Homebrew
3. **Problematic Commands**: pdflatex and kpsewhich
4. **Specific Error**: "LaTeX Error: File `article.cls' not found."

*Investigation*:

Permissions:

Permissions for /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin/:
bash
Copy code
drwxr-xr-x@ 488 johnterry  staff  15616 Nov 27 15:50 /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin/
Permissions for /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist:
bash
Copy code
drwxr-xr-x@ 30 johnterry  staff  960 Nov 27 16:12 /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist
Symbolic Link:
pdflatex is a symbolic link to pdftex:
bash
Copy code
lrwxr-xr-x  1 johnterry  wheel  6 Nov 27 12:57 /usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/universal-darwin/pdflatex -> pdftex
Behavior with sudo:
Commands work correctly when using sudo pdflatex or sudo kpsewhich.

*Attempted Solutions:*

Adjusted permissions using chown and chmod for relevant directories.
Set $TEXMFHOME to /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local.

*Questions:*

What could be causing this issue with pdflatex and kpsewhich only working with sudo?
Are there specific permission settings I should be aware of for LaTeX directories?
Is there a more effective way to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?
I appreciate any insights or guidance you can provide to help me resolve this LaTeX issue. Thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't install texlive from homebrew. If I remember correctly, this does some strange things which interfere with updates. Personally, I would install texlive directly from tug.org with normal user rights and not using sudo. If you run into a problem with permissions during installation, give yourself write access to the parent folder.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried installing texlive directly through tug.org and thus has not resolved the issue. Granting myself write access to the parent folder also did not resolve the issue.